# Handling multiple QNA KBs & skill bots in Luis

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Essentially, my company has a dispatch model chatbot built in Botframework, Luis & QNA Maker. We typically have one skill bot and one KB per subject area, which is leading to some issues in the dispatch model not knowing how to route an utterance because the skill bot intent & KB intent have so much overlapping vocabulary. Wondering the best way to handle this -- I've tried to clean up our utterances to make it clearer, but I'm wondering if I should just create a KB intent within the skillbot, and only let the dispatch route to skill bots. It just doesn't seem to fit within the design recommendations from Microsoft.

Current design:

```
     - Dispatch model
         - Area 1 skill bot intent
         - Area 1 KB intent
         - Area 2 skill bot intent
         - Area 2 KB intent
     - Skill bots
         - Area 1 skill bot
         - Area 2 skill bot
```

If no intents have a high confidence rating, then route to a chitchat KB.

My idea to fix the AI confusion:

```
- Dispatch model
     - Area 1 skill bot intent
     - Area 2 skill bot intent
- Skill bots
     - Area 1 skill bot
         - Area 1 KB intent
         - Area 1 other intents
     - Area 2 skill bot
         - Area 2 KB intent
         - Area 2 other intents
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Am i right saying for the same subject area, you have a Luis model and a QnA KB? if that is correct, why do you feel you have to do that

Comment: what is the requirement you are trying to achieve?